# Solr: List results by distance

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'd like to pass some parameters to Solr that should afflict the weighting of the results (I do not want to filter away results that do not match these criterias).

E.g. I'd like to have a language attribute, and if i pass the user's language to the search engine I'd like to have the results matching the language listed first. As a newbie to Solr I'd like to know if and how this is possible!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible by using boost functions. See this [FAQ entry](http:///solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29) or the description of [boost functions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29) for the DisMaxQueryPlugin (the dismax query parser is the default parser).